# Python input and output data in excel

Tags: python, excel, synonym

I'm really new in programming and Python. I would like to ask some newbie questions. I have an excel file which have words in a column. I want to read those word an generate the synonyms word in another excel file. Below is the words that i want to read from excel:

```
     |      A         |      B      |      C

1    |    mankind     |   liquid    |     air    

2    |    professor   |   steam     |     haze 

3    |    name        |   kind      |     awkward       

4    |    went        |   save      |     enemy
```

And this is my code:`

```
import nltk
import xlrd
import csv
import xlwt
import xlsxwriter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\runeza\Desktop\database.xlsx')
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

row_idx = 0

for col_idx in range(sheet.ncols):
    for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value #read content in column cell
        synonyms = []

        for syn in wordnet.synsets(cell):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(l.name())
                a = (set(synonyms))
        #print (a)
                wb = xlwt.Workbook()
                ws = wb.add_sheet("test")
                for i, col in enumerate(a):
                    for j, row in enumerate(col):
                        ws.write(i, j, col)
        wb.save("sample.xls")
```

`

However, this code does not translate all the words. In the output excel, it just print out the last word only and repeat the words in each column based on the number of letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are overwriting the sheet you create in each cycle of the inner loop, that's why you only see the last word. The repetition by the number of letters is probably due this line `for j, row in enumerate(col):` , col is probably a string and you are looping over the number of characters and writing cells inside that loop.

I did some modification to your code and now it should put replace each word in your sheet with all its synonyms comma-separated.

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("test")
for col_idx in range(sheet.ncols):
    for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value #read content in column cell
        synonyms = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(cell):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                print(l.name())
                synonyms.append(l.name())
        ws.write(row_idx, col_idx, ",".join(synonyms))
wb.save("sample.xls")
```

Notice that I create the output file **once** outside any loops, and I call `ws.write` only `sheet.ncols * sheet.nrows` times.